# (UK) If i inform the Jobcentre that I am paying someone's rent, will it harm their benefits claim?

Tags: united-kingdom, benefits

I am paying the rent for a homeless friend, and my/his rental costs are all over the shop due to poor/misunderstood information.  I have given him my mobile number to pass on to the landlord so that he can contact me to let me deal with the payments directly, but the landlord won't ring me (because I am not the Jobcentre), nor will he provide a receipt listing the dates covered by the payments made.

The manager of the local Jobcentre is also helping my friend, and I an considering sending them a letter to see if they can tell me what is happening with the rent with regards to amounts due, etc.

If I write to this Jobcentre manager and tell them that I have been, and continue to, pay my friend's rent, will it damage their ongoing benefits claim?

Comment: There isn't anything clearer information anywhere. I would ask the council to clarify, because it might be a bit convoluted. But it maybe considered charity(assuming you willn't ask it back) on your part, it mayn't affect your friend's status. I would advise to clarify it immediately with the council, so as not to jeopardize your friend's benefits.

Comment: I have looked at your SE profile, and I will find the details of my local Citizen's Advice Centre and go there ASAP, thank you.